# File.Exists returning true for a file that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-vista, filesystems

I'm working on an app that saves a file in `Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath)` where `FilePath = Application.ExecutablePath` that contains some information about licensing. If I run the program from VS it works OK but if I make an installer and install and then run it, the program thinks that the file already exists. I changed my program to show on a message box my `FilePath` and whether `File.Exists(FilePath)` returns `true` or `false`. So I looked in that path, enabled showing hidden and system files, F5'd several times and nothing. The file doesn't exist, but `File.Exists(FilePath)` returns true. Any idea why cold this be happening and how can I work around it?

I'm using Windows Vista, Visual Studio 2010, C# and created my installer with VS's Setup Project.

**Edit:** My path is: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Helium\License.xml*.

This is part of my code:

```
        MessageBox.Show("LicenseFileName: " + LicenseFileName); // LicenseFileName: C:\Program Files (x86)\Helium\License.xml
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(LicenseFileName);      // Nothing happens
        MessageBox.Show("File.Exists(LicenseFileName): " + File.Exists(LicenseFileName)); // File.Exists(LicenseFileName): true
```

Forgot to say that I already had the application installed before so the file used to exist. I uninstalled using Control Panel.

Comment: Is it an absolute path or relative path? Showing us the actual path may help too.

Comment: Try opening the file via Run. It could be super hidden. Also, I would recommend not using Windows Vista - for anything.

Comment: Are you literally saying `FilePath=Application.ExecutablePath;File.Exists(FilePath);`? A more complete code sample would be helpful here.

Comment: Yes I'm litteraly saying that.

Comment: Is UAC enabled on that PC? Maybe it doesn't give your application access to ProgFiles. Try elevating permissions. (ContextMenu->Run As Administrator)

Comment: Problem is that is app is intended to be installed on other people's PCs. I can't tell them get rid of Windows Vista or see if UAC is enabled.

Comment: If the permissions are incorrect, it would return false, not true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Comment: Well, I guess I shouldn't worry since the file can only exists (in this mysterious way) if I created it before which is basically all I need to know.

Comment: My gut feeling is.. that you have a folder C:\Program on you disk after this?

Comment: It happened to me before where i didn't show file extension in Windows Explorer and I looked for a file name something.pdf but it always returned false. The file name turned out to be something.pdf.pdf.

Comment: They should change File.Exists documentation to: Returns a random boolean value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are installing to a system folder, it is possible that Windows file virtualization kicked in and created a per user copy of the files. So your files may be located somewhere in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore folder

Comment: Yeah, I wasted a whole day the other day before tracking that one, I guess I should of asked on SO also :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Unity3D (whose authors never learned to write C# correctly -- they require "/" everywhere, instead of using the .net platform-local file APIs): this method always returns true if you pass it absolute paths *using Unity's linux-style Path.DirectorySeparatorChar*. I don't know how it's resolving them - there's nothing in the VirtualStore, nothing in the GetCurrentDirectory that could possibly match - and I don't see how you can debug File.Exists (horrible API).

So if your path looks like this (a valid Unity URL) and you're on Windows:

> C:/project/filename.txt

... C# will always return "yes, it exists".

But if you convert it to the correct Windows path:

> C:\\project\filename.txt

... C# will return true/false depending on whether the file exists.

**Note: formatting bugs in stackoverflow are corrupting the second path above. To be very clear: it should display the letter "C", followed by a colon, followed by TWO backslashes, and the words 'project' and 'file' are separated by one backslash.

Note: if you only have one backslash ... File.Exists again fails and returns incorrect values (always true). Microsoft's docs say the extra slash is not needed, but experimentally: it is.