# File.Exists returning true, not in Directory or VirtualStore

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a small problem which is similar to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308421/file-exists-returning-true-for-a-file-that-doesnt-exist)

HOWEVER

The code is litterally:

```
if(!File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\Log.txt"))
{
    //Create file
} else
{
    //Load file
}
```

However it always goes into the else block, as File.Exists is always returning true, but the file does not exist (or I can't find it)

The file is not in the specified directory

> C:\Windows\System32\Log.txt

and it is not in

> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Log.txt

(The userprofile is the user running the scheduled task/console app)

Just a quick note, I do not intend on storing this file in the System32 folder, this is a C# console app that I am executing as a Windows 7 Scheduled Task  - and without realising it the Schedule Task was setting the default start-in directory as C:\Windows\System32\

My curiosity has got the better of me as to where these files might be, and I would also like to clean up any floating files (if they do in fact, exist).

Lastly this is .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities that exist when referencing c:\windows\system32. One that you've noted, it could be redirected to %userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore. The other: if you're running as a 32bit process on a 64bit system, you will automatically be redirected to c:\windows\syswow64.

Check to see if log.txt exists in c:\windows\syswow64. If you want to reference certain locations on the system like c:\windows\system32\ or c:\program files\, you must change the build configuration to x64 or "AnyCPU".